# VS Code creates new lines when using refactoring variables tool (F2) in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, refactoring

this is a pretty simple question but I couldn't figure out the solution for this problem.

### The Problem

Let's say I have this simple Python code in VS Code IDE:
[image]

Let's say I want to refactor the variable "value" to be "value1", I press Fn+F2 on my computer and I edit the variable name:
[image]

This is the result of the code after the refactor step.
[image]

---

As you can see it adds automatically a new line without me requesting something like that.

### How I tried to solve this problem before asking here

I tried to search for a solution at Google, for example:

1. VS Code creates empty lines after refactoring a variable in Python
2. F2 refactor step creates new lines in VS Code, how to fix?
   And some more searches at Google but nothing helped...

There was some thread at Stack Overflow which said to click "Ctrl+Shift+P" and to open the "editor" and search for the solution there but unfortunately it didn't help.

I searched at VSCode official docs but I couldn't figure how where to search for this specific problem so I kinda got lost there.

My Extentions:
[image]

The solution should be really easy but I miss something.
I will be for your help, thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry, I could not reproduce your problem, could you try to annotate all the sets in your settings.json file, and reload the VSCode? If it still does not work, could you try to reinstall the VSCode?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Thanks for the response Steven, sorry for the late answer, I ended up removing visual studio code and then reinstalling it, then I installed all the packages and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 12):

Just encountered the same issue, with the same extensions installed. This appears to caused somehow by line-endings.

When using CRLF line endings I can reproduce the behaviour you've described (the option should appear in vscode at the bottom right of the window). Switching this to LF, I get refactoring working as normal.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, your solution sounds interesting but unfortunately, I ended up removing visual studio code and then reinstalling it, then I installed all the packages and that solved my problem. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: For me putting `"files.eol": "\n"` into the settings JSON file of VSCode fixed the issue; I made an answer below.

Answer (score 5):

For me the issue started when I disabled the `Pylance` extension.

Enabling the `Pylance` extension, then closing and reopening VSCode, got rid of the issue.

The role of Pylance is also mentioned in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17123).

Comment: It is happening because of Python language default server in vs code [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18143)

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to to answer of Michael: what worked for me was to fix `\n` as the EOL character by putting

`"files.eol": "\n"`

into the settings JSON file of VSCode.

Source: [this comment](https://github.com/pappasam/jedi-language-server/issues/159#issuecomment-930394612) referring to [this post](https://blog.boot.dev/clean-code/line-breaks-vs-code-lf-vs-crlf/).

Comment: this alone did not help for me